# Help Please The remix compiler is throwing this error and I'm really dumbfounded as to why. Any ideas? Thanks!

Tags: solidity, remix

How do I solve this error? I keep getting here from solidity:

```
SimpleStorage.sol:22:5: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
    favorivepeople.push(people(_favoriteNumber, _name));
    ^------------^
```

when compiling using pragma solidity ^0.6.0. Here is my code. Thanks!;

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    //this will be initialized to 0!
    uint256 favoriveNumber;
    bool  favoriteBool;

    struct people  {
        uint256 favoriveNumber;
        string  name;
    }
    people public _person;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
       _favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns(uint256) { 
       return favoriveNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public{
    favorivepeople.push(people(_favoriteNumber, _name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing the square brackets making it an array which has the push method

```
people[] public _people;

_people.push(people(_favoriteNumber, _name))
```

there's a bit of _favori**t**eNumber and _favori**v**eNumber in there too which I'm guessing is unintentional?

you've got a few other things to figure out, but at least that gets you moving forward :-)